# Pass Interface as Parameter

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I read the following example for altbeacon which is written Java (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html). I have to translate the code to c#..

```
    @Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");        
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
    }

    @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);        
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

i started like this now i got a problem passing the interface parameter like in the mentioned example..

```
        public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
        beaconManager.SetMonitorNotifier(...)
     }
```

can somebody please explain how to translate the code to c# ?

Comment: Not sure what the exact problem you are having... To pass an interface instead of concrete type that implements it, all you do similarly to this: 
public void SomeMethodName(ISomeInterface parameter){ };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your real question here is "is there an equivalent to anonymous classes in C#?". The answer to that is no.

Take a look at [Java: Interface with new keyword how is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157784/java-interface-with-new-keyword-how-is-that-possible). Java supports defining anonymous classes that implement an interface within a method. It is just syntactic sugar (or salt, depending on one's opinion on this feature) over defining a private class that implemements an interface.

So the solution when converting this code to C# is to create a private inner class and use that in the method:

```
class SomeClass
{
    ...
    public void OnBeaconServiceConnect() 
    {
        beaconManager.SetMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier());
        ...
    }

    ...

    private MonitorNotifier : IMonitorNotifier
    {
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");       
        }

        public void didExitRegion(Region region) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
        }

        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if you got me wrong. I was not looking for someone who finishes my code. I just wanted to know how to pass the parameter. Thanks anyway for that great response.

Comment: @AlexanderNovotny, I agree that remark was unfair. So I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous class cannot implement an interface in C#.
So not use anonymous class here :

```
    public class MyMonitorNotifier : MonitorNotifier {
...
}
```

and then :

```
 beaconManager.SetMonitorNotifier(new MyMonitorNotifier ());
```