# return an interface java

Tags: java, interface, return

I have an interface called shape and I have this method I need to implement

```
    public static Shape createShape(String shapeString, int panelWidth, int panelHeight) {
         Shapes shape = Shapes.valueOf(shapeString);
         Shape shapey = Shape(shape);
         Random random = new Random();
         int a = random.nextInt(panelWidth);
         int b = random.nextInt((panelHeight*panelWidth)/(4*a));
    }
```

I know I need to return a Shape, but I don't know how I'm supposed to do that

Comment: To return an object simply type in : return shapey;

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "I need to return a shape"? Please be more clear.

You cant instantiate an interface, you need to instantiate a class that implements the interface, for example:

```
class Square implements Shape { ... }

public static Shape createShape(String shapeString, int panelWidth, int panelHeight) {
    ...
    return new Square();
}
```

Comment: You can do it with an anonymous class instead of what you did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157784/java-interface-with-new-keyword-how-is-that-possible

Comment: I'm quite certain that is not what the OP is looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a method called `Shape` then this statement is invalid

```
Shape shapey = Shape(shape);
```

and is not going to compile...
on the other hand...returning an interface is not more as the same as returning a class, in the sense that you need to add the return statement and the interface, or some objects that implements the interface...

```
 public static Shape createShape(String shapeString, int panelWidth, int panelHeight) {
         Shapes shape = Shapes.valueOf(shapeString);
         Shape shapey = Shape(shape);
         Random random = new Random();
         int a = random.nextInt(panelWidth);
         int b = random.nextInt((panelHeight*panelWidth)/(4*a));
         return shapey;//this will do the trick
    }
```